# What kind of lenses will work on an entry-level Nikon DSLR?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, nikon-d3300

I am total noob at cameras/lenses so I don't know what I am buying. My cousin has asked me to bring 70-300mm or 18-300mm lens for his D3300. Now, I don't know what lens will be compatible with the D3300.

I tried visiting a camera store (https://www.vistek.ca/) and was blown away with lens options. Can someone guide me, what brand, mount, or whatever technical terms are are compatible with D3300?

Comment: Lenses are often a very personal choice. Since your cousin asked you to bring a lens, I doubt you're expecting to surprise him with a gift. Ask him which of the lenses that fit whatever budgetary criteria you have will work best for him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nikon D3300 takes lenses with a Nikon F mount. I would also recommend looking for lenses that have focus motors built in (AF-S on Nikon brand lenses, USD on Tamron or HSM on Sigma), as the D3300 does not have a focus motor in the camera body. You can use lenses without focus motors but on the D3300 they would be manual focus only.

In the ranges your cousin has asked about, you might consider:

[Tamron AF 70-300mm f/4.0-5.6 SP Di VC USD XLD](https://www.amazon.ca/Tamron-70-300mm-4-0-5-6-Digital-Cameras/dp/B003YH9DZE)
[Nikon AF-S 70-300mm f/4.5-5.6 G IF ED VR](https://www.vistek.ca/store/CameraLenses/226702/nikon-afs-70300mm-f4556-g-ed-vr-telephoto-zoom-lens.aspx)
[Nikon AF-S 55-300mm f/4.5-5.6 G ED VR II DX](https://www.vistek.ca/store/CameraLenses/251749/nikon-afs-55300mm-f4556-g-ed-vr-ii-dx-telephoto-zoom-lens.aspx)
[Nikon AF-S 18-300mm f/3.5-6.3 G ED DX VR II](https://www.vistek.ca/store/CameraLenses/274438/nikon-afs-18300mm-f3563-g-ed-dx-vr-ii-zoom-lens.aspx)

Please note, I am not making any recommendation as to which, if any, of these lenses would be most suitable, as I have no idea what your cousin would like to use the lens for.

You could also try asking your cousin if he has any preference, as he might have had a specific lens in mind and simply assumed you would know which one he wanted.